# Cannot resolve symbol "FirebaseAuth"

Tags: android, android-studio

I still have this error inspite of me adding
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0" to the build.gradle(app).Please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, add rules to your root-level build.gradle file, to include the google-services plugin and the Google's Maven repository:

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services 
plugin
}
}

 allprojects {
// ...
repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
     }
  }
}
```

Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the 
    apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
// ...
 }

 dependencies {
 // ...
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
 // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
 }

 // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make sure that your activity is importing the Firebase Auth module.
In the .java file for your activity (eg. Login.java):

```
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
```